# Catalina recent items stack in dock no longer working

Tags: dock, catalina

I have been using a stack of recent items in my dock for some time now, following the instructions [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/15/add-recent-items-menu-mac-dock/).  Since upgrading to macOS Catalina, I've noticed that the stack has disappeared from my dock.  I've tried re-instating it by using the code supplied at the aforementioned site (code included below), but to no avail (no error messages or anything, and nothing changes in the dock).  Is anyone aware of a way to reinstate this or an equivalent alternative?  I have looked at using a recent folder by creating a smart folder, but this doesn't appear to enable me to limit the number of items included.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = { "list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile"; }'
```

(Note that I did include the killall function following this as well, so it's not a matter of restarting the dock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent items stack has been gone since Juli 5th (Catalina beta 3). Haven't found any documentation on why it is gone and how to reinstate it. The array is indeed added under persistent others in the com.apple.dock.plist, but nothing happens. Would really love to see it back.
The smart folder option is no option...

Answer (score 2):

I have found a work around. There is still the 'Recents' folder in the Finder Sidebar. Right click on this and select 'Add to Dock'.

The 'Recents' Stack will appear in the dock, and should update automatically.