# Can I show drives in the dock?

Tags: big-sur

Drives appear in the sidebar of Finder windows, but I would like them to appear in the dock (as well), with a way to easily eject them. Is there a setting or other technique to make this possible?

Comment: You can show then directly on the desktop. Would that do?

Comment: Another suggestion: drag the `/Volumes` folder to the Dock

Comment: @Redarm nice idea, but unfortunately that doesn't give an easy way to eject the drives.

Comment: @PatrickSanan If displayed as "Fan", or "Grid", the volume can be dragged to the trash to be ejected.

Comment: @Redarm That seemed cool, but trying it froze my dock..

Comment: @PatrickSanan It's working as expected here on Big Sur.  The only fault I can see with this method: when a volume is being actively used/tied up by some process, the eject will fail silently, where the Finder would display a message.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to macOS Catalina, you can add a Recent Volumes stack to your Dock.

1. Add the ‘recents-tile’.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = {"list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile";}' && killall Dock
   ```
2. Right-click the ‘Recent *’ stack and set it to show ‘Recent Volumes’.

In macOS Catalina, this functionality was removed: [Catalina recent items stack in dock no longer working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/373667/37797).